# aspnet with visual studio code restoring packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnx, visual-studio-code

So I've decided to give it a go and try visual studio code and c# development on my mac.

The setup is annoying, but I can live with that. Now I'm running into 2 specific issues that prevent me from even getting through the HelloWorld steps...

1) I used `yo aspnet` to create the project from the given templates. It then tells you to run `dnu restore` which works fine, for the most part until I run into the following issue:

> Installing
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.1.0.0-rc1-final
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   '/Users/lostballoon/.dnx/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/1.0.0-rc1-final'
>   is denied.

Why only this package? Why not the ones before this? And Why am I getting this?

I run into this same issue even when trying to restore the packages of an `EmptyApplication`:

> Installing Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.1.0.0-rc1-final
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Users/lostballoon/.dnx/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler/1.0.0-rc1-final'
>   is denied.    at System.IO.UnixFileSystem.CreateDirectory(String
>   fullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)

2) In VSCode, when choosing `dnx: Run Command` or `dnx: Restore Packages` I get a warning pop-up that says the following:

> OmniSharp server is not running.

I have no clue what is wrong and how to get it working.

Comment: Environment information: MacBook Pro running OS X v10.11.1 (15B42) El Capitan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue when installing things today. I got similar errors when it tried to install things to:

/Users/yourname/.dnx/packages/

What I did was open Terminal, change directory to /Users/yourname/, and then run (replacing "yourname" with your username):

sudo chown -R 'yourname' .dnx

That gives you ownership of that folder, so that you can then change directory to .dnx and create the 'packages' folder (mkdir packages within .dnx folder). Once I made that 'packages' folder I was able to then restore.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it as soon as I get the chance today

Comment: Yup, that seems to have been the issue, for some reason my .dnx and .bash_profile belonged to root

Comment: Do you have any idea for the 2nd issue in the question? It's still giving me that in VSCode